# How to scrape data from https://www.fiverr.com/

Tags: php, curl

I need to scrape data from https://www.fiverr.com/

Basically i actually need to read data from following sub page
https://www.fiverr.com/gigs/gigs_as_json?host=search&type=single_query&query_string=pet&search_filter=rating&category_id=3&sub_category_id=49&limit=48

```
$url = 'https://www.fiverr.com/gigs/gigs_as_json?host=search&type=single_query&query_string=pet&search_filter=rating&category_id=3&sub_category_id=49&limit=48';
$html = file_get_contents( $url);
```

But its not returing data.
I also tried with curl as well.
No success at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need to scrape this. This is JSON data that you can use. What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried? What code do you have right now?

Comment: But how? Any example?

Comment: hey it is JSON data, so you need to encode the data's  // $json = file_get_contents('url_here');
$obj = json_decode($json);

Comment: I need to convert that json data into array format after then i will read that array and enter into my database. But its not working with either file_get_contents and curl as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website you tried to fetch tries to set some cookies, and then tells you to send another request to the same URL with your new cookies. PHP's `file_get_contents()` doesn't send cookies by default, but it follows the redirect, meaning you enter in a 302 redirect loop.

To avoid this loop, you need to manually set the cookies :

```
$url  = 'http://www.fiverr.com/gigs/gigs_as_json?host=search&type=single_query&query_string=pet&search_filter=rating&category_id=3&sub_category_id=49&limit=48';
$opts = array('http' => array(
    'header' => 'Cookie: locale=en%3B0%3Bfalse; suggested_locale=1;',
));
$ctx  = stream_context_create($opts);
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $ctx);
```

The variable `$data` contains binary data since the website gzipped the content. So you may want to have the plain data :

```
$data = gzdecode($data);
```

Now you have JSON-encoded data that you can parse using `json_decode()`.